# Increase CPU Usage in a controlled manner programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, cpu-usage

I want to increase my CPU usage through a java program, albeit in a controlled manner. Say, a user can specify a parameter like "high", "medium" or "low" and I should be able to increase the CPU by a certain amount depending on the user's choice. Lets say for high I want it to increase by 5%, for medium by 3% and for low by 1%. 
Is this possible with a clean and efficient method (not just using while and for loops)? IF yes, then how and what will be the precision and accuracy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the CPU load incurred by a Java program by inserting sleep statements (e.g. [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)) in your code, using variable delays to change the load. The simplest case would be a sleep statement in a loop, executed in a separate thread for each CPU core that you want to load.

That said, Java is *not* suitable for this task - not if you actually need the kind of precision that you are describing. The garbage collector and other factors make its behavior rather unpredictable.

In my own applications I regularly get throughput variations in the 10% range for the same input, with no apparent cause. It is for this reason that Java is not considered suitable for real-time applications either.

It might help us provide a better answer if you mentioned for what purpose you need to do something like that - and, perhaps, why you need to do in *Java*...

Comment: Actually, my application which simulates the processing capabilities of any other application, uses another JAVA library, which is not available in a different language. That's why I need to do it in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Write a java program which will have only one thread, that is, in your main method create an infinite while loop, which keeps executing.
You will find that the CPU usage will increase.
In case you don't have any sleep in this while loop, you will find that your program will be taking up almost 100% CPU.
The more sleep you put in this while loop , the lesser CPU usage your program would take.

Answer (score -1):

CPU usage is controlled by the underlying Operating System. The OS will determin the CPU usage  neccesary to perform a given task. 
Since CPU usage is controlled by the OS, it cannot be controlled directly through java.

The only thing you can do is change a threads priority to control the CPU usage indirectly or you can put the thread to sleep for a given time.

Comment: Ok. Would you care to elaborate? I'd like to learn about it then.